# Bluetooth receiver doesn't appear in sound options 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, bluetooth

I've got a SMK Link Nano Dongle Bluetooth 4.0 LE + EDR Bluetooth adapter for my Acer Aspire. I've got an Onkyo receiver with Bluetooth capabilities. I've got it both paired and connected with my laptop but it won't appear in the sound options. I see many people have had similar problems with headsets and keyboards. I've tried just about everything that worked for other people and have had no such luck. Wondering if anyone has any clue as to what I could do here.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem? I'm experiencing the same thing

Comment: @Benoir yes, sorry it took so long to get back to you. I forgot my log in (womp) Turns out it was just the bluetooth adapter I had. Swapped it out for a CenDyne and it works like a charm!